# Reading or creating empty shapefile in R

Tags: r, polygon, polygon-creation, union, rgdal

I have several polygon shapefiles that I need to merge into one using a loop in R.
I want to start with an empty shapefile and merge it with the existing shapefiles. All shapefiles will be chacked before the merge that they have the same fields.

I can think of two options:

1. create an empty shapefile in ArcMap and read it into R.
   I tried this with readOGR and got an error:

> ```
> library(rgdal)
> EI_GIS_ALL = readOGR(dsn = EI_GIS_ALL_dsn, layer=EI_GIS_ALL_FileName)
> Error in readOGR(dsn = EI_GIS_ALL_dsn, layer = EI_GIS_ALL_FileName) : 
>   no features found
> ```

2. Create an empty shapefile in R and use union to merge it with existing shapefiles.
   The union is like in maycca's solution in [Merging multiple SpatialPolygonDataFrames into 1 SPDF in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155328/merging-multiple-spatialpolygondataframes-into-1-spdf-in-r)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Spacedman nailed it but, I would add that you can avoid unique row.name issues by using sf and then coercing to sp. First create names vector `shp <- list.files(getwd(), "shp$")` then read in data `s <- lapply(shp, function(x) sf::st_read(x) )` finally, merge and coerce to sp `s <- as(do.call(rbind, s), "Spatial")` With large data you will also get better read times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to use another pattern, eg special treatment of the first item:

```
first=TRUE
for(shp in shapefiles){
   # this function reads in a shapefile from shp and returns sp object:
   shpdata = read_in_and_check(shp)
   if(first){
      output=shpdata
      first=FALSE
   } else {
      output=bind(output, shpdata)
   }
}
```

or get your shapes into a list and use `do.call` with `bind`:

```
# shpdatas becomes a list of sp-class objects:
shpdatas = lapply(shapefiles, read_in_and_check)
output = do.call(bind, shpdatas)
```